# Cannot composer dump-autoload - file put contents error?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

On a Ubuntu 16.04 server.

I get the error:

```
 file_put_contents(/var/www/example.com/site/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have:

1. Change permission of storage dir to 755
2. Made sure the www-data user has correct usage rights

I still get the error. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: do you have installed `selinux`? or some auditory service? In my box I had the same problem, once I allowed http service with `setsebool -P httpd_unified 1 ` everything got ok

Answer (score 4):

First of all
After installing Laravel, you should change the permission of some specific directory.
Use these commands.

```
// If your project's directory is owned by root then,
sudo chown -R <username> path_to_laravel_project_directory

// Then change these persmissions (from the root of the laravel project directory)
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/

// At the end please generate your project key
php artisan key:generate

// Now you can use
sudo composer dump-autoload
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set these permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 bootstrap/cache/
sudo chmod -R 755 vendor/composer
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

Comment: @panthro, exactly the same error with `autoload_namespaces.php`? Try `777` on the `vendor/composer` directory.

Comment: Yes same error, have just tried 777, same error again.